# How to crawl a website that requires an account in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape data from "https://seekingalpha.com/article/4414043-agenus-inc-agen-ceo-garo-armen-on-q4-2020-results-earnings-call-transcript". Below is my code. However, although it gives me the HTML file, I cannot access the actual article content.

This website requires a login to see their articles. And I have passed that stage, but I cannot get the full article. Below is my code.

```
import requests
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

USERNAME = "USERNAME"
PASSWORD = "PASSWORD"

LOGIN_URL = "http://www.seekingalpha.com/login"
URL = "https://seekingalpha.com/article/4414043-agenus-inc-agen-ceo-garo-armen-on-q4-2020-results-earnings-call-transcript"

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
ua=UserAgent()

hdr = {'User-Agent': ua.random,
      'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
      'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
      'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
      'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

def main():
    session_requests = requests.session()

    result = session_requests.get(LOGIN_URL)
    tree = html.fromstring(result.text)

    payload = {
        "email": USERNAME,
        "password": PASSWORD,
    }

    #result = session_requests.post(LOGIN_URL, data = payload, headers = dict(referer = LOGIN_URL))
    result = session_requests.post(LOGIN_URL, data = payload, headers=hdr)

    #result = session_requests.get(URL, headers = dict(referer = URL))
    result = session_requests.get(URL, headers=hdr)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content,"lxml")
    print(soup)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You can create an example account if you wish to test it out. How do I get the full article?

Comment: You might have to check out Selenium if the website is using JavaScript to get the article. Beautiful soup won't work there

Comment: Are you sure the login is working? Have you looked at `result.text` from the login?

Comment: `requests` is an HTTP client; it retrieves the contents of files at specific URLs. BeautifulSoup is an HTML parser, it parses HTML markup. Neither of these will interpret/execute JavaScript on a retrieved page. If the content of the article is "painted" using JavaScript, the scraping method you're currently using simply will not work. Instead, opt to use a browser control tool like Selenium or Puppeteer, which enables your script to control a real instance of Chromium and retrieve the contents of pages as a normal user's browser would.